# what does L represent in "<any hex number>L"

Tags: c++, hex

I am looking through some c++ code and I came across this:

```
if( (size & 0x03L) != 0 )
    throw MalformedBundleException( "bundle size must be multiple of four" );
```

what does `L` stand for after the hexadecimal value ?

how does it alter the value `0x03` ?

Comment: [C++ Integer Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00a1awxf.aspx) " long-suffix: one of `l` `L`"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means Long, as in, the type of the literal 0x03L is `long` instead of the default `int`.  On some platforms that will mean 64 bits instead of 32 bits, but that's entirely platform-dependent (the only guarantee is that long is not shorter than int).

Answer (score 8):

This suffix sets the type of the numeric literal. `L` stands for `long`; `LL` stands for `long long` type. The number does not need to be hex - it works on decimals and octals as well.

```
3LL  // A decimal constant 3 of type long long
03L  // An octal constant 3 of type long
0x3L // A hex constant 3 of type long
```

Answer (score 2):

It means so-called long-suffix of integer literals and denotes that the type of the literal is `int long` The integer literal in your example is hexadecomal integer literal of type `int long`.
You can meet also two `LL` (or `ll`) that denote type `int long long`